# Why aren't Callen's thermodynamic surfaces in agreement with the extensiveness of entropy?

Tags: thermodynamics, entropy

I am reading Callen's book on Thermodynamics, chapter 4, and I can't figure out why the following surface seems not to respect the extensiveness of entropy (if we multiply $X_j$ and $U$ by 2 we should have twice as much entropy right?)

[image: Thermodynamic surface of a simple system]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An extensive property [depends on the size of the object](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intensive_and_extensive_properties). Absolute entropy (J) is an extensive property. Molar entropy (J/mol) is an intensive property.

We can double internal energy U (J) by methods other than doubling the size of the object. For example, double the absolute temperature of an ideal gas at constant volume. Since $U = C_V \Delta T$, the internal energy will double without changing the size of the system.

So, while S(U ...), doubling the extensive value of U does not lead to the commensurate conclusion that the extensive value of S must therefore also double.

The same reasoning applies when we might multiply any other parameter that we might put in the list S(U ...) *individually, by itself* with two exceptions. The exceptions are volume (size) and possibly amount (mass or moles).

But then, when we double the size, we will double all other extensive parameters and the amount (mass or moles as well).

Therefore, an equation that says $S(\lambda U, \lambda V, \lambda n_j, \ldots) = \lambda S(U, V, n_j, \ldots)$ is acceptable. **ALL** parameters are being multiplied equally.

Otherwise, perhaps your concern is really about the scales of the three axes shown. Since they have no values and no scale markings, we really have no idea that the picture does or does not violate the numerical relationship. Notice that as $U, X$ both increase, so does $S$. So, the picture is correct qualitatively.

Comment: Do you mean that $S(U,V,\lambda n_i,...)=\lambda S(U,V,n_i,...)$? I saw in class that $S(\lambda U,\lambda V,\lambda n_i,...)=\lambda S(U,V,n_i,...)$, which is what I think isn't in agreement with the surface above.

Comment: I would not take exception to the notation $S(\lambda U, \lambda V, \lambda n_i, \ldots ) = \lambda S(U, V, n_i, \ldots)$ because $\lambda$ multiplies all terms *but especially volume* equally. I have documented this directly in a modification.